# NSURLSessionUploadTask (1) uploads data, (2) hangs for ~200s, (3) repeats

Tags: ios, nsurlsessionuploadtask

Here's where I am so far with `NSURLSessionUploadTask`:

- iOS application starts an `NSURLSessionUploadTask` using POST
- server receives HTTP POST request
- server reads content of the request so data is uploaded
- iOS application calls  `URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:` repeatedly ending with a final call with `totalBytesSent` equal to `totalBytesExpectedToSend`
- server sends HTTP response to iOS consisting of the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.10
Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2015 16:15:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html

<html><head><title>POST RESPONSE</title></head><body><p>The file was uploaded.</p></body></html>
```

- iOS application receives this response (confirmed via Wireshark)
  [image: Wireshark]
- iOS application **does not** call the following methods to complete the upload task like it supposed to:

  - `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate: -> URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:`
  - `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate -> URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:`
- instead after hanging for ~200 seconds, the iOS application repeats the data upload task

This data upload, HTTP 200 response, ~200 second hang process appears to repeat indefinitely.  Why aren't  `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate: -> URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:` and `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate -> URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` being called once the HTTP response is received by the iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

After correctly uploading the data via an HTTP request to the server, the iOS application received the HTTP response, but because there was no `Content-Length` transmitted 
in the HTTP response, the iOS application had no way of knowing when the HTTP response had ended. Two possible solutions:

- server closes socket after HTTP response is transmitted
- `Content-Length` is included in HTTP response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.10
Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2015 16:15:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 96

<html><head><title>POST RESPONSE</title></head><body><p>The file was uploaded.</p></body></html>
```

I tried both solutions sucessfully, but the `Content-Length` solution is superior because it reduces network overhead by allowing iOS application and 
server (assuming the server supports `keep-alive`) to maintain the socket connection for future HTTP requests.

I've also put a very basic NSURLSessionUploadTask example application and webserver on github [here](https://github.com/drbobdugan/NSURLSessionUploadTaskExample.git).